# PHP send variable to another page for excel export

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a build query. Basically, the user can enter data into a text box, use a dropdown selection, and/or radio button. All of this information is sent to a series of $_GET variables that are added to a $where variable that is used for a main query.

Here is what the some of the build query looks like:

```
 <?php
   $bol = $_GET['bol'];
   $container = $_GET['container'];
   $city = $_GET['city'];

   $select = "";
   $where = "";

   if($container != ""){
      if( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
       $where .= " dispatch_read.CONTAINER_NUMBER = 
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($container)."'";
         }
   if($bol != ""){
     if( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
       $where .= " dispatch_read.BOL_NUMBER = 
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($bol)."'";
         }
   if($city != ""){
     if( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
           $where .= " dispatch_read.ALTERNATE_POINT_IMPORT =
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."'";
         }      

   if ($where != "")
     $select = "SELECT * FROM dispatch_read WHERE " . $where .";";
     $QueryResult = @mysql_query($select) or die ();
     $resnum = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);
```

At this point, I can retrieve data from the table and display it in a grid.

I will go ahead and show a little bit of code which shows the grid:

```
 if ($resnum == 0){
   echo "<div><h2>Your search returned no results</h2></div>";
   }
 else{
   echo "<table>\n";
   echo "<thead><tr>" .
   echo "<th>BOL</th>" .
   echo "<th>CONTAINER</th>" .
   echo "<td>CITY</th>" .
   echo "</tr></thead>\n";
 while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE){
   echo "<tbody><tr>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[BOL_NUMBER]}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[CONTAINER_NUMBER]}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[CITY]}</td>";
   echo "</tr></tbody>";
   echo "</table>\n";
   }
 }
```

There are many more search criteria as well as rows that are displayed.

*** UPDATE ***

In my main page, which is called dispatch.php, I have a javascript functions that calls a page called getreport.php:

```
  function getreport(){
    window.location="getreport.php?where=$where";
  }
```

The part of the above code, you can see where I tried to send the $where to that page.  Of course, that didn't work.

What I need to do is send the $where variable (which will container 1 or all variables) to another page where there is another query that I will plug the $where variable into.

Basically, the user should be able to print the grid to excel.  I've tried several methods to do this.  I tried to extract the parameters from the URL, but I don't think that will work because some of the parameters might be blank, which I think will throw the query off.

To summarize, how can I send the $where variable to another page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you opening/closing the tbody and closing the table inside your while loop?

Comment: Good catch. I'll fix that.

Comment: You shouldn't really send the $where value to another page but the parameters used to build it and then rebuild it on the next page.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using the mysql_* functions any more as they are deprecated. Consider using the mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: Any idea on how to send the parameters to another page and then rebuild it?

Comment: Just include the file, that is a more secure approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

You want to use a session, so the user can store variables that are used in between request.

For Example:

```
<?php
   $bol = $_GET['bol'];
   $container = $_GET['container'];
   $city = $_GET['city'];
session_start();
   $select = "";
   $_SESSION['where'] = "";

   if($container != ""){
      if( $_SESSION['where'] != "" ) $_SESSION['where'] .= " AND ";
       $_SESSION['where'] .= " dispatch_read.CONTAINER_NUMBER = 
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($container)."'";
         }
   if($bol != ""){
     if( $_SESSION['where'] != "" ) $_SESSION['where'] .= " AND ";
       $_SESSION['where'] .= " dispatch_read.BOL_NUMBER = 
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($bol)."'";
         }
   if($city != ""){
     if( $_SESSION['where'] != "" ) $_SESSION['where'] .= " AND ";
           $_SESSION['where'] .= " dispatch_read.ALTERNATE_POINT_IMPORT =
           '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."'";
         }      

   if ($_SESSION['where'] != "")
     $select = "SELECT * FROM dispatch_read WHERE " . $_SESSION['where'] .";";
     $QueryResult = @mysql_query($select) or die ();
     $resnum = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);
```

Comment: I actually tried to use a session variable to make this work previously, but not like this.  I'll test this immediately.  Quick question:  does the session reset when the user makes a change to their search?

Comment: First a word of advice, anytime you use `$_SESSION` you need to have already called `session_start()` within that script. Now, pretty much, changing from `$where` to `$_SESSION['where']` makes the variable available anywhere you call `session_start()`, which can be thought of as a making it into a global variable. You can destroy the session or reset it whenever you like, or unset a particular session variable. The session data is stored on the server, and a session id is stored as a cookie on the client, which will persist usually as long as the user keeps the browser open.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am finally able to export to excel. However, I need to figure out how to end each session as the report will bring back the same data after the user makes a change in their selection. Ending the session doesn't sound too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you just need to add the &where=urlencode({your where var}) but you didn't include the part of your code that calls the page.

Comment: I updated the code that contains javascript that calls the other page.

Comment: See how I wrapped it in urlencode()? Then you may or may not have to urldecode on the other end...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

// Please connect to the database using PDO
$dbname = 'database';
$user = 'user';
$pass = '';

try {
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

// Get $_GET vars
$bol = $_GET['bol'];
$container = $_GET['container'];
$city = $_GET['city'];

$select = $where = '';

// If the var is empty, it will be false
if ($container) {
    // Using the PDO prepared statements tokens/variables
    $where = ' dispatch_read.CONTAINER_NUMBER = :container';
}
if ($bol) {
    if ( $where ) { $where .= ' AND ' }
    $where .= 'dispatch_read.BOL_NUMBER = :bol';
}
if ($city) {
    if ( $where ) { $where .= ' AND ' }
    $where .= 'dispatch_read.ALTERNATE_POINT_IMPORT = :city';
}

if ($where) {
    // Create the tokens/variables for pdo
    $vars[':container'] = $container;
    $vars[':bol'] = $bol;
    $vars[':city'] = $city;
    // Concatenate the query
    $select = "SELECT * FROM dispatch_read WHERE {$where}";
    // Prepare that query for execution
    $sttm = $DB->prepare( $select );
    // Executing the query with the $vars array
    $sttm->execute( $vars );
    // Get all the rows in a variable
    $allRows = $sttm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Instead of redirecting, just include the file
    include 'process_data.php'
}
```

Then in process_data.php

```
// process_data.php
// This is a really, really, REALLY dirty way to generate a Excel File, just for the sake of testing
// Use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ instead
<?php if (!$allRows): ?>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div><h2>Your search returned no results</h2></div>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php 
    ob_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=result.xls ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
    ?>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BOL</th>
                    <th>CONTAINER</th>
                    <th>CITY</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($allRows as $Row): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $Row['BOL_NUMBER'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Row['CONTAINER_NUMBER'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Row['CITY'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php endif ?>
```